# SagePay fails when forcing https

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, opayo

I'm using the following in my `.htaccess` to force https on;

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

However this seems to cause SagePay to throw a `5003` error and a `500` http error.

The site has a valid SSL and was just installed yesterday and if I comment out these lines it works correctly with SagePay. MY callback pages are linked as https so SagePay redirects back to my site with https on so it's not as if SagePay is looking at the address and sees that it's being changed.

I don't *have* to force https, it won't be the end of the world, but I want to do so for the obvious benefits of https. Am I doing anything wrong, is there something I can do to fix this problem and keep forcing https?

Comment: Can you check Apache error.log to see why 500 is coming.

Comment: I get a couple of PHP notices for `Undefined variable:...` there's only 2 variables listed, but maybe 10 times combined.

Comment: That may not cause 500. I think you're not looking at Apache error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting SagePay support directly and looking at their logs for an example transaction I was able to see that our callback url (that was sent along with the post request to SagePay before the user even got to the SagePay payment portal) was manually set to be http rather than https.

This meant that when SagePay tried to post back to our website to see what to do next it was using an http url which would then have been redirected via our htaccess rules.

I can only assume SagePay's security considered this as tampering or something like that and considered that the transaction was not safe.

After manually changing our callback url to https, everything works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

5003 [Sage Pay Error Code](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/error-codes/error-internal-server-error)

ERROR : Internal server error.

Explanation: If you receive this message, a code related error has occurred on the Sage Pay systems. This could have been caused by the information posted to the Sage Pay server or by an issue with the Sage Pay server.

Solution: Please reveiw the information your server is posting to the Sage Pay server.  If you are using FORM integration, ensure the encryption password is correct and casing correct as this error can be returned if incorrect. If you are unable to identify the cause, can you provide the TxID so Sage Pay can view the transaction logs? Transaction logs are to be less than 72 hours old.

Comment: I've contacted your support regarding this via your website - thanks

Comment: This really isn't helpful as an answer - it's copy and pasted directly from your documentation and has little or no relevance to the actual, very specific question that was asked.